# Gstreamer zero copy dmabuf encoding

Tags: c, gstreamer, dma, zero-copy, vaapi

I want to encode a framebuffer I got via dmabuf into a video stream.

I have a dmabuf file descriptor which contains the framebuffer. I got the filedescriptor from the intel i915 driver via `ioctl VFIO_DEVICE_QUERY_GFX_PLANE`.
Now I want to encode it per zero copy in gstreamer into a video stream (h264, h265 etc...). I push the single frames per `appsrc` into the gstreamer pipline. Since I use intel hardware I thought it makes sense to use VAAPI.

The problem is that the sink pads of vaapi only support `video/x-raw` and `video/x-raw(memory:VASurface)` and I have `video/x-raw(memory:DMABuf)`.

Is there any way to convert `video/x-raw(memory:DMABuf)` to `video/x-raw(memory:VASurface)` (zero copy) or import the DMABuf directly as `video/x-raw(memory:VASurface)`?

Alternatively is there a framework which is better suited than vaapi?

My code to push the frames into gstreamer currently looks like this:

```c
    GstMemory* mem = gst_dmabuf_allocator_alloc(vedpy->gdata.allocator, dmabuf->fd, dmabuf->width * dmabuf->height * (dmabuf->stride/1024));
    vedpy->gdata.buffer = gst_buffer_new();
    gst_buffer_append_memory(vedpy->gdata.buffer, mem );
    
    gsize offset[GST_VIDEO_MAX_PLANES] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    gint stride[GST_VIDEO_MAX_PLANES] = {dmabuf->stride, 0, 0, 0};
    gst_buffer_add_video_meta_full( vedpy->gdata.buffer, GST_VIDEO_FRAME_FLAG_NONE,
                                    GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_ENCODED,
                                    dmabuf->width, dmabuf->height, 1, offset, stride);
    GstFlowReturn ret;
    vfio_encode_dpy *vedpy = container_of(dcl, vfio_encode_dpy, dcl);
    g_signal_emit_by_name (vedpy->gdata.source, "push-buffer", vedpy->gdata.buffer, &ret);
```

And my pipline:

```c
char launch_stream[]  = "appsrc name=source ! "
    " video/x-raw(memory:DMABuf),width=1024,height=768,framerate=0/1,format={BGRx,BGRx:0x0100000000000001} ! "
    " vaapipostproc !"
    " vaapih265enc ! 
    ...
```

which obviously does not work, because vaapipostproc can not be linked with the filter.